# HTML5 аудиоплеер

Tags: jquery, php, html5, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Много рылся в интернете, и ни как не могу найти плеер на `HTML5`, с настраиваемым дизайном и плей листом. Предложите свои варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/). [Здесь](http://www.jplayer.org/2.0.0/demo-02/) демка его с плейлистом, на сайте можно скачать ее код. Неплохо документирован.

Answer (score 2):

См.: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/124313/

Comment: А можете предложить что нибудь полегче??)

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать сервис uppod.ru Там настраивается дизайн и плейлисты и все подробно расписано

Comment: @trane294 там же они все на flash?

Comment: Там новая версия на HTML 5